# How to set text dynamically to texbox in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

Dear Fellow StackOverFlow-members,

I try to dynamically create texboxes in a userform and set default text depending on value from a tab.

First the user fill in textboxes like in the photo 
 [image: first_step] 
When he clicks the button above, it calls the function that create textboxes in the same userform. Exactly as much as the total of values of the textboxes, futhermore for value "0" it counts as 1 textbox to add.

What I want is when it encounters `0` value I want the new texbox created to set defaut text as "null". Like so : 
 [image: result_expected]

My code :

```
For i = 0 To UBound(tabValTextBox)
            valTemp = tabValTextBox(i)
            If valTemp = 0 Then
                iTextBoxMasqueA = iTextBoxMasqueA + 1
                Set textBoxCableA = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
                colTextBoxCableA.Add textBoxCableA
                With textBoxCableA
                    .Name = "cable" & iTextBoxCableA
                    .Top = iTextBoxCableA * textBoxCableA.Height + 50
                    .Left = 150
                    .Text = "Nul"
                End With
            Else
                For j = 0 To valTemp - 1
                    iTextBoxCableA = iTextBoxCableA + 1
                    Set textBoxCableA = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
                    colTextBoxCableA.Add textBoxCableA
                    With textBoxCableA
                        .Name = "cable" & iTextBoxCableA
                        .Top = iTextBoxCableA * textBoxCableA.Height + 50
                        .Left = 150
                    End With
                Next j

            End If
        Next i
```

`tabValTextbox()` is a tab containing the values of the left textboxes.
However the result I get looks like this  : 
 [image: result_reached] 
 I don't get as much textboxes as expected. 
I don't understand where I'm missing something. I want to learn from this, so if possible, explain me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: I suspect it's because you're setting the `.Top` of your `textBoxCableA` using only `iTextBoxCableA` - you're not considering `iTextBoxMasqueA` in the calculation so if a zero box exists then although all the boxes are being created (and drawn) - some are on top of others. You might be able to prove this by setting the `.Left` for the zero boxes to say, 140 so you can see when two overlap.

Comment: @CLR You're damn right. I changed .Left for 0 boxes and they all appear. However I don't see to display them in columns.

Comment: So instead of `iTextBoxCableA` *or* `iTextBoxMasqueA`, create a new index that increments in *both* cases and use that index to multiply in both cases. - or just get rid of one as per my answer below.

Comment: @CLR  Yes you're right my bad. I didn't see I misspelled the index. I think I could watch this for hours and not see that. Thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(tabValTextBox)
    valTemp = tabValTextBox(i)
    iTextBoxCableA = iTextBoxCableA + 1
    If valTemp = 0 Then
        Set textBoxCableA = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
        colTextBoxCableA.Add textBoxCableA
        With textBoxCableA
            .Name = "cable" & iTextBoxCableA
            .Top = iTextBoxCableA * textBoxCableA.Height + 50
            .Left = 150
            .Text = "Nul"
        End With
    Else
        For j = 0 To valTemp - 1
            Set textBoxCableA = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
            colTextBoxCableA.Add textBoxCableA
            With textBoxCableA
                .Name = "cable" & iTextBoxCableA
                .Top = iTextBoxCableA * textBoxCableA.Height + 50
                .Left = 150
            End With
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

I've moved the `iTextBoxCableA` increment outside of the zero condition, and removed the `iTextBoxMasqueA` increment entirely as you weren't using it.

I can't test this myself but I think it'll sort the problem of overlapping out.

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I did. I jsut made me realise that I defined `iTextBoxMasqueA` and then used  `iTextBoxCableA`. Even in your first comment I didn't realise that. I guess I needed someone new to look at it